# Terminology: List of all boxing and muay thai technique terms with example photos

Tags: technique, kickboxing, boxing, terminology, muay-thai

I'm looking to put together a list of all the technique terms for: boxing, muay thai.  Such as the names for all the different punches, kicks, knees, elbow punches, etc...

Anyone know if there is a list of these available online somewhere (pics are not a full requirement, as I can find images from other resources once I have a complete list of the names).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kind of similar to [this question](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/1742/347), but not identical.

Comment: Check out "[Muay Thai - The Art of Fighting](http://cdn.preterhuman.net/texts/survival/Ruerngsa,%20Yod%20-%20Muay%20Thai%20-%20The%20Art%20of%20Fighting.pdf)" it contains hundreds of descriptions of techniques with photos.

Answer (score 2):

Muay Thai moves list with links for pictures and demos. You could even contribute to update.

http://www.blackbeltwiki.com/muay-thai-techniques